# How to take first character from 2 words

Tags: javascript

I have input = "Graha Cinere". And I want the output just "GCi". So G it's take from first characters in first words and Ci from second words.

```js
    val = "Graha Cinere"
    val.match(/\b(\w)/g).join('')
```

**Current output :** GC

**Expected Output :** GCi

I wish there's an answer from my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello Bai!**

Although the use of **Regex** is extremely useful and practical for this and some other situations with more complex scenarios, I would recommend you to first take a look and give a try to the native string methods coming along with most languages, that will give ya a better scope of what you can do with the language itself to find a prompt solution to your cases and if not, then you go to the next step by getting the extra help from some other tools such as [**RegEx**](https://regexr.com/), [**Underscore**](http://underscorejs.org/) or its successor [**Lodash**](https://lodash.com/) just to name a few:

I put this small snippet of JS together for you to take a look at a simpler way to handle this case. This is not the only way to do it, but it is merely made in the language in use.

Cheers, pal!

```
let str="Graha Cinere";
(() => {
return str.charAt(0).concat(str.substr(str.indexOf(' ')+1,2));
})();
```

Comment: Anytime, we are glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of ways to do this. Firstly you can use a regex to match the single character at the start of the first word and two characters at the start of the second word and then `join` those parts.

```js
val = "Graha Cinere";

out = val.match(/^(\w)\w*\s+(\w{1,2})/).slice(1).join('');
console.log(out);
```

Secondly you could split the string on space and then take the first character of the first result and the first two characters of the second result and `join` them:

```js
val = "Graha Cinere";

out = val.split(' ').map((v, i) => v.slice(0, i+1)).join('');
console.log(out);
```

Comment: @Bai no worries - I'm glad it was useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

first split then take two words

```js
val = "Graha Cinere";
parts = val.split(" ");
neededStr = parts[0][0] +parts[1][0]+ parts[1][1];
console.log(neededStr);
```

Also, You can use String slice

```js
let val = "Graha Cinere";
let parts = val.split(" ");
neededPartOne = parts[0][0];
neededPartTwo = parts[1].slice(0,2);
exactNeeded = neededPartOne + neededPartTwo;
console.log(exactNeeded);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will give you what you're looking for-

```
val.split(" ")[0][0] + val.split(" ")[1][0]
```

Comment: The split method will take some time and you are using split two times. I believe if you store the split output to one variable and reuse it. it will take less time. Look my answer if you need.  This is just a suggestion. Thanks